# Select contacts to register for events does nothing - how to fix?

Tags: civievent, drupal, actions

User selects one or more contacts, then selects action 'Register participants for event' and nothing happens - zilch.  In fact, none of the actions work at all.  This system was restored last Sunday after a migration failure, so I rebuilt triggers with civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1 but this didn't fix the problem.  So perhaps something broke in the restore?  Release 5.28.3 / Drupal. Ideas on how to fix, please?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by disabling the Bootstrap theme and then re-enabling it. Other users had also had this problem, usually involving Shoreditch and/or Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in CiviSpark, so there is no theme to disable/enable

Comment: @DanielKohn - Welcome to SE.  If you have a problem with Spark you would be better asking in the Spark support channel on https://chat.civicrm.org/